# C言語の整数リテラルの最後につける「L」の使いどころはどこですか？

Tags: c

C言語の参考書では、整数リテラルの最後に「L」を付けるとlong型になると説明されています。
確かにメモリ上のサイズは「1」と「1L」で違っていました。
※sizeof(1)は4、sizeof(1L)は8でした。

#### 質問

メモリ上のサイズの他に「1」と「1L」で違いはあるのでしょうか？
「1」と「1L」で演算結果が異なるケースや呼び出した関数の振る舞いが異なるケースが知りたいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

整数リテラルの型が変わることによる影響はいくつかあります。分かりやすいのは、リテラル同士を演算してオーバーフローする場合でしょう。

`100000000`（1 億）は 32bit signed int の範囲ですが、その 2 乗は 32bit signed int の範囲を超え、64bit signed int の範囲に入ります。このため 32bit signed int として 2 乗を行うと、結果も 32bit signed int として格納され、オーバーフローします。

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld\n", (long)(100000000 * 100000000));  /* オーバーフローします */
    printf("%ld\n", 100000000L * 100000000L);        /* 10000000000000000 が出力されます */
    return 0;
}
```

[(Wandbox)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sAND6bH4HmYAJpC9)

他にも、上のプログラムでも不自然に long にキャストしている理由でもありますが、`printf("%ld", 1);` の挙動は未定義な一方 `printf("%ld", 1L);` は正しく 1 を出力するという違いも生まれています。

また、`L` だけだと使いどころが分かりづらいですが、整数リテラルの末尾記号には他にも `UL` などがあり、それらと組み合わせると他にも使いどころが生まれてきます。詳しくは [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13134956/5989200) をご覧ください。

Comment: 「L」を付ける意味についてけっこう長いこと考えていたのですが、全然思い至りませんでした。質問してよかったです。これまで怪しいところはすべてキャスティングしていましたが知識が結びつきました。